# How can I protect already built spring web application against XSS and CSRF attacks?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I have completely build my web application using spring 4.2.0.RELEASE. Now during testing, I find out that application is vulnerable to XSS and CSRF attacks. I need to know How can I protect it with minimum efforts(/ changes in already existing code).

I have refer the this [spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html) doc: It says,

> As of Spring Security 4.0, CSRF protection is enabled by default with
>   XML configuration.

So I think I need to use spring security. So I added pom dependancies :

```
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

But then all guides and tutorial I refer to configure Spring security ask for, changes in login functionality. Basically spring security takes care of login. But I dont want to change that, I just need to use some of the features of spring security. Basically CSRF token and XSS related features, can I do that?

I added pom dependency and thats it. What else I need to do? Is there any good reference that I am not able to find. I am using STS for project
I have referred to [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) : But it also ask for spring authentication.

Comment: Unless you specify `csrf = "disabled"` in `security.xml`, it'll enabled automatically from v4.x..

Comment: I dont have security.xml file

Answer (score 0):

First you need to integrate spring security to your web application. There are many tutorials for it. Then you can enabled like

```
<http>
  <!-- ... -->
  <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

In the spring security documents, http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure, it is stated that;

```
As of Spring Security 4.0, CSRF protection is enabled by default with XML 
configuration. If you would like to disable CSRF protection, the corresponding 
XML configuration can be seen below.

<http>
    <!-- ... -->
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>

CSRF protection is enabled by default with Java configuration. If you would like to disable 
CSRF, the corresponding Java configuration can be seen below. Refer to the Javadoc of csrf() 
for additional customizations in how CSRF protection is configured.

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: well I understand that I need to use spring security but as I said all tutorial I found ask me to change login functionality which I dont want to do at this stage. Can you give link to some good tutorial? I already have gone through that document you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: I don't know your current login functionality. If you use your login with ajax, you can follow this tutorial https://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/implementing_ajax_authentication_using_jquery Or if you post your current login page, we can find an easy way to change it using spring security.

Comment: my login is normal.. AD authentication from ldap server. I dont want role based functionality from spring as I have already taken care of role access. I dont want that `<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>`